# issue involving serialized object and eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a Serializable object that I am sending from my android emulator to a java server on the same computer. I have been able to send raw data but when I send the object I have an issue. The issue is that I have made the server in textpad and the androind app in eclips. The the object the server is looking for is of type point but eclipse is adding the file structure to it. ie help.help.point. Do I need to put all my files at the root in eclips and get rid of the package thing or can I deal with it on the server size when casting it. Sorry if this is not clear

Comment: the definition of your object must be identical for serialization and deserialization. That includes any package you may be using. I recommend sharing a library (a jar or something) between both projects.

Answer (score 0):

A fully qualified classname consists of package name and class name, therefore you should rather add the package name to your textpad edited class than to omit it in eclipse.

Best way of course is as @njzk2 already suggest in a comment, to share common code (otherwise it will become a maintenance nightmare)